# Gain access to Azure Key Vault from several different principals/users using access policy

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

I have a terraform code that deploys an Azure key vault using the code:

```
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}


resource "azurerm_key_vault" "keyvault" {
  name                        = "${local.environment}"
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id

  sku_name = "standard"

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
    key_permissions = [
      # List of key permissions...
    ]
    # All permissions listed currently.
    secret_permissions = [
      # List of secret permissions...
    ]
    storage_permissions = [
      # List of storage permissions...
    ]
  }
}
```

I have a certain code that runs under a different principle that is used when deploying this code. So `data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id` (aka: *The object ID of a user, service principal, or security group in the Azure Active Directory tenant for the vault.*)  would be different inside that code and the secrets are therefore inaccessible to the code.

How can I amend the `access_policy` so different users/service principals can access the same data vault simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`azurerm_key_vault_access_policy` resource.](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/key_vault_access_policy) . So you'd change your code to:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "keyvault" {....}

//add one of these for each user
resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "kvapta" {

  key_vault_id                        = azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.id
  tenant_id                           = var.identity.tenant_id
  object_id                           = var.identity.principal_id

  certificate_permissions = []

  key_permissions = [
  ]

  secret_permissions =[]

  storage_permissions = [
  ]

}
```